# LTS versions installed by stack

Tags: haskell, package-managers, haskell-stack

Is there a stack command one can run to get a list of all the LTS versions installed by stack on my system?

Comment: Is this question even sensible? I thought an LTS was essentially just a collection of package versions. What would "installing" a collection of version numbers mean?

Comment: @DanielWagner Sometimes if I'm creating a new package, I usually want to be using the same latest `lts` present in my system for that new package so that it can use cache from those locally stored snapshot.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about `stack` command but you can do it with `bash` command:

```
$ ls ~/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/
```

For me it prints:

```
lts-8.13  lts-8.15  lts-8.17  lts-8.21  lts-8.3
```

Instead of `x86_64-linux` should be your arch. But you don't need to remember it. Just press `TAB` after `snapshots/`.